# IISNode Returns 404 for Routes, but Node Returns Routes

Tags: node.js, express, iis, iisnode

I am hosting a NodeJS app on a Windows Server via IIS using iisnode. The app has Express routes and when I launch the app on the server via node (ex. NPM Start), it executes the Get routes without issue.

However, when running through IIS, it has a 404 for the routes. It loads the main page and page running Swagger without issue... but any Get route that is executed generates a 404. The IIS_IUSRS account has full control of the whole app folder. I suspect it is something in the web.config not properly rewriting for the Get routes (I had thought this occurs by default).

Here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="LogFile" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.js\.logs\/\d+\.txt$"/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?"/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="StaticContent">
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="DynamicContent">
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" />
             <security>
       <requestFiltering>
         <hiddenSegments>
           <add segment="node_modules" />
         </hiddenSegments>
            <verbs>
                <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
                <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
                <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
                <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
            </verbs>
       </requestFiltering>
     </security> 
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is my server.js (I have tried the port with or without 3000 (ex. const port = process.env.PORT) but no difference in behavior):

```
// MODULES AND REQUIRES
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const swaggerJsDoc = require("swagger-jsdoc");
const swaggerUi = require("swagger-ui-express");
const objectMapper = require('object-mapper');
const cors = require('cors');

// Require Routes
var api1 = require('./routes/api1.js')
var api2 = require('./routes/api2.js')

// PORTS AND BASIC EXPRESS APP SETTINGS
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// CORS ALLOW ALL. NOTE IP RESTRICTIONS ARE IN PLACE
app.use(cors({
  origin: '*'
}));

// ignore request for FavIcon. so there is no error in browser
const ignoreFavicon = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.originalUrl.includes('favicon.ico')) {
      res.status(204).end();
  }
  next();
};

// Configure nonFeature
app.use(ignoreFavicon);

// Root Route - Serve Static File
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/client.html'));
});

// SWAGGER UI CONFIGURATION

// Primary Swagger Options
const options = {
  customCss: '.swagger-ui .topbar { display: none } .swagger-ui .scheme-container { display: none }'
};

// Custom Swagger Options: https://swagger.io/specification/#infoObject
const swaggerOptions = {
  swaggerDefinition: {
    info: {
      version: "2.0.0",
      title: "My App",
      description: "This page lists the available APIs within my app and allows you to test them.",
      contact: {
        name: "My Name"
      },
      servers: [{"url":"http://localhost:3000", "description": "Development server"}]
    }
  },
  // ['.routes/*.js'] Location for APIs
  apis: ["./routes/*.js"],
};

const swaggerDocs = swaggerJsDoc(swaggerOptions);
app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocs, options));


// ROUTES
  app.use('/api1', api1)
  app.use('/api2', api2)  

// APP LISTEN WITH SSL/HTTPS
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: I have dug through multiple logs, including the ones generated by iisnode. They all state a 404 on the route which is likely tied to the way IIS manages the routing to the Node app

Comment: Do you have tracking failed requests log? If so, you can post it.

Comment: I am only outputting the port number. If throws a “Cannot Get” error in the browser console (404). My question is how to configure this as it only seems to work if I run it local on port 3000

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: This is not a IIS defect. It’s understanding why my routes are not found when in IIS because the port generated when IIS starts is random. Shouldn’t the full node app just work on any port?

Comment: First of all, you should check whether that 404 answer is created by IIS or by node, ie if the request is even forwarded to node and if yes, if it's rewritten correctly. Ie, enable as much logging as possible on both sides to see what request arrives at IIS, what is forwarded to node, what arrives at node and what is returned by node.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to resolve this by running a reverse proxy and setting Node to run over Port 3000. For the SSL address, I needed to also add the certificate in the Node app.